# Why didn't the Sith clone Inquisitors?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

I was just wondering why the Sith didn't clone Dark Side Adepts or Inquisitors, so that there would be an army of Dark Side users. Darth Vader did it to Starkiller, so why not others?

Is there any explanation in canon or legends that explains why the Sith didn't clone an army of Dark Side users?
(Not ones powerful enough to take down the master (Sidious) or the apprentice (Vader))

Comment: I would hazard a guess and say economics. Inquisitors were a means to an end- not a permanent fixture. The amount of cloning that was used to create one successful sith (starkiller)... In any case, the Emperor probably didn't see the inquisitors as worth the price. Cloning would be expensive, failure-ridden and in the end he would probably end up killing the inquisitors after they served their purpose.

Comment: I don't just mean Inquisitors though, how about cloning force sensitive users during the clone wars? Users like Asajj Ventress;

Comment: I believe it goes against the belief of the jedi to clone a force sensitive. While the sith/seperatists may not have been against cloning force-sensitives, there was always the natural power-struggles that are caused by the sith (which is why the rule of 2 was implemented). In short, the sith will not make sith because they will by necessity kill each other. Additionally, one could conjecture that even if clones were made, because the force will attempt to maintain balance, they may not be force sensitive, even though the original template was a force sensitive. However this is speculation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cloning force sensitives was not a particularly reliable idea.  It worked out with Starkiller but in other cases the clones were not very mentally stable.  For example, the Thrawn trilogy had two rather unstable clones:

> Joruus C'baoth (clone of Old Republic Jedi master Jorus C'baoth) and Luuke Skywalker (clone of guess who).

Also, correct me if I'm wrong, as I haven't played much of the Force Unleashed games but looking it up, it looks like the Starkiller clone also had many failed attempts before eventually ending up with one that worked.

Comment: You could also state that _The Force Unleashed_ games are not canon anymore, so it's possible that cloning Force-sensitives isn't possible at all in canon.

Comment: @Gallifreyan I did say that I wanted answers from canon _or legends_

Comment: Also Luuuke Skywalker: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Luuuke_Skywalker

Comment: Just as an additional note, force sensitive clones had to be cut off from the force during their accelerated growth, or they went insane.  This is from the original (legends) Thrawn trilogy.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is mostly sticking to the current canon and assuming cloning a force sensitive is possible (since the GAR was a clone army). 
We could see this as a result of two things:-

1) Palpatine stopped the cloning process after the end of the clone wars and instead recruited normal people for his Imperial army. The reason behind this is expenses. **Palpatine instead wanted to focus his credits on building his ultimate weapon, a death star.**
I think it is fairly reasonable to agree that ***a death star is far more formidable and instills more fear in systems*** than maybe a bunch of force sensitives would have. Many people don't even know about or don't believe in the force (stated twice by two different characters in ANH).

2) (I think this one is far more important when we take only Palpatine into the picture and not the whole Empire).

Palpatine didn't really want many force senstives around. He had Vader to represent him almost everywhere. Note that the inquisitors were dispatched mainly to hunt down the remaining Jedi and potential Jedi, and would have probably been killed off by Palpatine after their use was over.

It is also important to note that Palpatine did face a problem with a clone in the past when his order 66 plan was almost ruined. ***Each clone has independent thinking and thus having more of these force sensitives increases the chance of one becoming hungry for more power and turning on the Emperor himself***, after all, they too were dark side users (although not as strong as Vader or Maul).

I do have one possible reason (again for canon) about how cloning could not have worked. Since the clone army were clones of non force sensitives, maybe cloning might have been easier. However, there is a possibility that midichlorians interfere with the process or they cannot be cloned.

For the **legends**, I cannot be too sure. I mean Starkiller is a perfect example of how powerful a clone can be, but also strongly enforces my point number (2) about how a clone is an independent thinker and can turn on their master (although later in the game we do get to know that the cloning process has been perfected).

Answer (score 1):

**Force-sensitivity is not entirely genetic.** We know that Force is strong in Skywalker family. Yet, Anakin's mother was not Force sensitive. Since you mentioned Legends, Palpatine's family was not Force sensitive (novel *Darth Plagueis*) . Darth Bane's parents (*Darth Bane* trilogy) also were not Force sensitive. In Legends, there were examples of children from powerful parents without or with reduced Force sensitivity. Example would be [Ania Solo](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ania_Solo).

It looks like midichlorians have a will of their own, and would not allow to be simply copied. Also, it is worth mentioning that in Legends attempts to transplant midichlorians with blood infusions and similar procedures have failed.